# Paypal Express option is missing at checkout - Magento 1.4.2

Tags: magento, paypal, checkout, cart

I've copied new Paypal and Checkout template folders into my site from all sorts of magento versions, and I still can't get the icon to show at my checkout. It works on a few other sites I've created.

Does anyone have any ideas why I can't get any instance of paypal express to show up on my site? I want it mainly in the checkout/cart area-

**Magento 1.4.2**

Things I have checked:

1. Base Currency is USD.
2. Replaced all files in Checkout(template) folder with different version, no changes.
3. Replaced all files in Paypal(template) folder with different version, no changes.
4. Replaced XML files for Checkout/Paypal with Newer, and older versions.
5. Verified my Paypal Express (and paypal pro) settings in the backend, these are identical to another working installation I have.

My head aches from this. Any ideas?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a temporary solution to this issue-

I added the express checkout button myself in the checkout, and linked it to http://www.mydomain.com/paypal/express/start/

If they have items in their cart, this URL will proceed into the paypal express checkout.

Hope this helps someone out there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely aware about Paypal Express but in your configuration, the value of "Enable Paypal Guest Checkout" is set to "No".

During the checkout process, at the cart page, the customer may not be yet logged, then Paypal is not shown. But if you are already logged, I think it will be shown.

If you set the config to yes, guest customer could use it but they won't create an account or log in ! Depends on your needs!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I tried it toggled "Yes" and "No" with no luck (dumped cache, too).